# Illegal character range in regex

Tags: regex, character, range

I am getting an error message with my regex. Here is the message:

Message: Illegal character range near index 17
.*[~?!@#$%^&*()_-+=[]|\;:‘“<>,.?/]{8,9}.*
                 ^

Note: the ^ inthe end of the message is below + sign.

Here is my code:

```
    private static final String PASSWORD_PATTERN_SPECIAL_8 = ".*[~?!@#$%^&*()_-+=[]|\\;:‘“<>,.?/]{8,9}.*";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are working in Java.

Try:

```
 1. `Pattern.Quote()` function

 2. \Q(characterlistHereWithoutbracket)\E

 3. Escape the character manually by using `\` in front of the
    character.
```

Second option uses any thing as a literal that lies between `\Q..\E`.

**EDIT**

Regarding second option I mean you can use it as given in [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#qe) example. See *Special Characters*.

Or you can check if the qouted pattern your regex engine is using is similar to something like this or not:

```
\.\*\[~\?!@\#\$%\^&\*\(\)_-\+=\[]\|\\\\;:‘"<>,\.\?/]\{8,9}\.\*
```

NOTE: This pattern is obtained by .Net `Regex.Escape()` function.

Comment: Yes. And I'm still getting the error even after escaping the characters that needed to be escaped.

On the second option, Im quite confused. Please elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, the solution applies to Scala as well.

In places where Pattern.Quote (and equivalents in diff language) is hard to use, your second suggestion works like a charm: \Q and \E.

I used it like this in scala regex pattern: "^\\w[\\w\\Q -=:;/.$\\E]*".r

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the double quote inside the string

```
private static final String PASSWORD_PATTERN_SPECIAL_10 = ".*[~?!@#$%^&*()_-+=[]|\\;:‘\“<>,.?/]{10,20}.*";
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. After a thorough check, it turns out the ' and " is different because I copied it from MS Word, from a document I created. I also escaped the single quote. Thanks.

Comment: The squiggly lines were removed, but the error is still the same. it is still pointing below +.

Comment: Going along the same lines, in the text the leading "[" looks italicized. Could it also be a freak character from Word? In fact that appears true for some of the other characters like the "?" and the "!". Maybe paste through notepad to make sure you have all valid.

Comment: I had it pasted in notepad. Here is my code now. private static final String PASSWORD_PATTERN_SPECIAL_8 = ".*[~!@#$%^&*()_-+=[]|\\;:\'\"<>,.?/]{8,9}.*"; still not working.

Comment: Hmm. Notice you have bracket as one of the characters. The "]" would be taken as the end of the class. Try escaping it. Might as well escape both.

Answer (score 0):

Special RegEx characters

```
.\\+*?^$[]{}()|/
```

Within brackets only escape

1. `^` at start,
2. `-` in middle,
3. `]`, and
4. `\\`.

The dash needs to be escaped if it is not the first or last character in the brackets.

The `\_-\\+` sequence looks for all characters between `_` and `+`.

The end bracket may also need to be escaped.